# Show multiple shared Exchange calendars on external video screen/wall

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, calendar

Not sure if this is the best stackexchange for this question, but let's give it a try.

In our company we have several shared calendar resources (in Microsoft Exchange) into which people enter their planed vacation days, conference visits and many more. Furthermore some people share their calendar with their teammates.

Now I wonder if their is any software that can be configured to do kind of a slide show through such calendars showing them nicely on a larger screen (on our desk or outside the office for everybody). It should not be Outlook itself but more a presentation style.

I would like to configure a slide for "vacation" that is a summary of one or more calendars and "today", which is again a summary (or tabular view) of many stakeholders.

Is there any recommended software out there?

Thanks for any hint.

Here's a sample how it should look like:

[image: Vacation overview]
[image: Conference room overview]
[image: Group of shared calendars]